# fuelux : start datepicker on monday

Tags: datepicker, culture, fuelux

I try to load the datepicker of fuelux with start of the week to Monday.

i have already try this:

```
$('#myDatepicker').datepicker({
culture: 'fr',
format: 'L' });
```

but without success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be, per [datapicker options](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#datepicker-usage-options):

```
$('#myDatepicker').datepicker({
  momentConfig: {
    culture: 'fr',
    format: 'L'
  }
});
```

However, this will only set the format of the input box--not the calendar. I'm not sure if there is a way to have the calendar start on Monday (you can change the day names at the top to French, of course). The team was not aware that the "French week" started on Lundi. Please [post an issue](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/new).